# XMLHttpRequest sends url as response text, Firefox doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, firefox

I have some javascript that sends a XMLHttpRequest to a PHP file. This PHP file sends a response, and javascript is supposed to create a URL and redirect to it, using the response text as a parameter. In all other browsers it works fine, but Firefox won't include the response text in the URL.

This is the javascript example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'filename.php', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e){
    var id = e.currentTarget.responseText;
    var urlWithId = "restofurl?id=" + id;
    window.location.href = urlWithId;
}
xhr.send(fd);
```

and filename.php is just a number at the moment:

```
<?php
    echo "3";
?>
```

I have tried putting other parts of the url (up to the whole url) in the php part, and firefox always cuts out exactly that part. I have also tried copying the response several times to different variable, copying it character by character, putting it in a function that just returns the input again,...

This is only going to be on my own computer, so I don't need to worry about any security issues, so I'm mostly looking for an easy way to cheat around this rather than the way it would be done professionally. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Onreadystatechange doesn't necessarily mean it's done when it triggers does it?

Comment: Is there any error or message popping up in the firefox dev tool console?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange seems to indicate an alternative way to get the response text.

Comment: try to set window.location instead of window.location.href

Answer (score -1):

This is a basic example, you actually have to test `readyState` status. If i remember well, it is also safer to set the event function before sending the request (not really sure of that).

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        //do something with this.responseText
    }
};
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.send();
```

**EDIT**:
This is one of the reasons why i use frameworks, for the old browser support, but this is not an answer. To be more precise, in the past (present?), browsers used to implement exotic functions. It's been a long time i didnt bother to use XHR objects directly, last time it was for file uploads with loading bar (canvas). It shows you the basic way to handle some stuff. This is longer and a bit old fashioned, but well, it works.

```
function customXHR(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest;
    }else{
        try{ //the weird ones
            return new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        }
        catch(ex){
            return null;
        }
    }
}

var xhr = customXHR(), pleaseStop = false, startDraw = false;

if(xhr){
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e){
        var jsonRep;
        if(!pleaseStop){
            //did use a JSON response
            jsonRep = $.parseJSON(e.target.responseText);
            //do the rest, we finished
        }
    }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener('error', function(e){
        //error
        pleaseStop = true;
    }, false);
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
        //why not let this as an example!
        //file_size must be retreive separately, i fear
        if(e.lengthComputable && file_size > 0 && !pleaseStop && startDraw){ draw_progress(e.loaded / file_size); }
    }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e){
        //can be used too
    }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e){
        if(e.target.status == 404 && !pleaseStop){
            //error not found
            pleaseStop = true;
        }
        if(e.target.readyState == 2 && e.target.status == 200){
            startDraw = true;
        }
        /*if(e.target.readyState == 4){
            //not used here, actually not exactly the same as 'load'
        }*/
    }, false);

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.send();
} //else no XHR support
```

Comment: Aaaaah thank you! That makes sense, because the readyState is changed several times, and only the last time there is actually a response. That also explains why it would always print the correct url if I just made it appear somewhere on the same page without redirecting...
Now it would be interesting to know why the other browsers didn't do this.

Comment: this is just a basic example, it has not the widest support (if you want retro-compatibility). For brower use, it will always depend on the javascript implementation of the browser itself, it may even not be standard. Note that this example does not handle error states, i'll edit for that if i have time

Comment: added a sample code that shows you how to use status, readyState and events to handle a response with a wider (longer) browser support